# Internet access from Host-only network

Tags: networking, ubuntu, ip, vmware, iptables

### Initial situation

I need to share internet between two VMWare images that work within host-only network, where one host would be a server and another a client.

**I'm working with VMWare Workstation and have two kinds of Virtual Networks:**

1. VMnet4:

   - Type: Host-only
   - Subnet IP: 192.168.237.0/24
2. VMnet8:

   - Type: NAT
   - Subnet IP: 192.168.56.0/24
   - Gateway IP: 192.168.56.1
3. PC's IP in a context of VMNet8 network is 192.168.56.5

**With such Virtual Networks I have two hosts with following configurations:**

**1. KaliLinux 2019.3:**

*ip addr*

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:b5:bd:69 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.56.10/24 brd 192.168.56.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:feb5:bd69/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:b5:bd:73 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.237.1/24 brd 192.168.237.255 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:feb5:bd73/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

*ip route*

```
default via 192.168.56.1 dev eth0 onlink 
192.168.56.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.56.10 
192.168.237.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.237.1
```

*iptables rules*

```
#!/bin/bash

outer_interface=eth0
inner_interface=eth1
inner_subnet=192.168.237.0/24
internet_ip=192.168.56.10

sudo iptables -F
sudo iptables -t nat -F
sudo iptables -t mangle -F
sudo iptables -X

sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i $inner_interface -o $outer_interface -s $inner_subnet -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i $outer_interface -o $inner_interface -d $inner_subnet -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -P FORWARD DROP

sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s $inner_subnet -o $outer_interface -j SNAT --to-source $internet_ip

echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

**2. Ubuntu Desktop 18.04 - as a client**

*ip addr*

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default glen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.8.0.1/8 scope host lo
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens33: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default glen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:66:6c:4a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.237.2/24 brd 192.168.237.255 scope global noprefixroute ens33
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:fe66:6c4a/64 scope link
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

*ip route*

```
default via 192.168.237.1 dev ens33 proto static metric 20100
169.254.0.0/16 dev ens33 scope link metric 1000
192.168.237.0/24 dev ens33 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.237.2 metric 100
```

---

### Problem

With configuration specified above I can't access Internet from Ubuntu client.

---

### Quetsion

What do I wrong? Is my configuration correct? What I need to do with my configuration?

Comment: `internet_ip` should be `192.168.56.10`, not `192.168.56.1`

Comment: @TomYan doesn't suit - stil doesn't work. From client I can't even ping 192.168.56.0 subnet host

Comment: Can you even ping `192.168.237.1`? If so check the counters if `iptables -nvL FORWARD`. (`internet_ip` should definitely be the IP assigned to `outer_interface` btw, if it isn't always gonna be the same, use `MASQUERADE` instead of `SNAT`.) For the record, I know nothing about vmware, no idea if it prevents anything.

Comment: @TomYan specify as you said. Is there any manipulations with DNS on the client side, that I should to apply?

Comment: Well, if you are using a DNS server with its public IP directly, then probably not.

Comment: Vmware Workstation Host Only is isolated. Change that Guest to NAT to be able to connect to other guests or outside

Comment: @John Does that mean that from the outer side (Internet side) an interface should be bridget?

Comment: Bridge or NAT will both work. Bridged is easier.

Comment: @John But you can't create more than one NAT in VMWare

Comment: True but guests can have different IP addresses on one NAT subnet. However, Bridging should be easier as you have outside IP resources

Comment: @John Should I have two NAT network adapters on my server host?

Comment: Look in VMware Network Editor (Run as Administrator) and see what NAT settings you have. I think there may be just one.